# How to hide some data from logs while installation process?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

I have created one installer using InstallShield tool. In that I' creating XML file using XML file changes. In that I have added some nodes and keys. In one of the key I have added some sensitive data like password. And when I'm creating installer and running it then in logs that sensitive data gets written in plain test. So I want to hide that data from logs as well. So how I can do this ?

Also when I'm using Set Property Custom Action, that time as well the sensitive field also gets printed in logs. So I want to hide this as well. How I can hide data to get print in logs in both scenarios ?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a property value whose contents you don't want seen in the log, add it to the list in MsiHiddenProperties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370308(v=vs.85).aspx

In InstallShield this seems to be the IDE way to do this:

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/HidingProperty.htm

Comment: I have already added that property in MsiHiddenProperties. But while adding that property in XML file using XML File Changes functionality if IS, then that value get printed in plain-text.

Answer (score 2):

Your worried about a log file having a plaintext password in it but your going to have an xml file with the same password in it persisted after the installation?

I'd suggest using a custom action to encrypt the property before passing it off to IS XML changes custom actions.  Then have the application decrypt the password.  It's not a perfect solution but better then where you are now.

Comment: This approach helps address the fact that the some actions will log the values they write, and since they format the text they may be unable to verify whether it includes a sensitive value.

Comment: @Christopher: Can we skip to write data to logs while doing an action of XML File changes (ISXMLInstall) ?

Comment: No. That's closed source and you can't change it's behavior.